# wrap matching words in a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on a functionality which will convert matching `tags` or `keywords` into links inside particular `DIV` tag.

Background: I store article body & keywords related to articles in database & while display article in a web page i pass keywords as and array to jQuery function which then search's through the  text inside  `<div id ="article-detail-desc" > ...</div>` and converts each matching element into link.

My code works fine but it has flows.

1. It doen't search for words it search's for any match even if it is part of a word or HTML element which breaks my HTML code.

how can this function be modified so that it also search for matching words

```
function HighlightKeywords(keywords)
{        
    var el = $("#article-detail-desc");
    var language = "en-US";
    var pid = 100;
    var issueID = 10; 

    $(keywords).each(function()
    {
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+this+")", ["gi"]);
         var rs = "<a class='ad-keyword-selected' href='en/search.aspx?Language="+language+"&PageId="+pid+"&issue="+issueID+"&search=$1' title='Seach website for:  $1'><span style='color:#990044; tex-decoration:none;'>$1</span></a>";
        el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
    });
}   

HighlightKeywords(["Amazon","Google","Starbucks","UK","US","tax havens","Singapore","Hong Kong","Dubai","New Jersey"]);
```

Link on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dgysc/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). So you'd have that:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)", ["gi"]);
```

**Edit:**
Quick hack to be sure it's not matching the `US` inside the html elements:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]);
```

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker sorry, not used to create regex this way, you'd have to double-escape. Edited.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker isn't this what you're searching for? [It seems](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgysc/29/) to be working just fine.

Comment: It is not working for me. Please mover over the link and see what link looks like `http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dgysc/29/show/en/search.aspx?Language=en-%3Ca%20class=%27ad-keyword-selected%27%20href=%27en/search.aspx?Language=en-US&PageId=100&issue=10&search=US%27%20title=%27Seach%20website%20for:%20%20US%27%3E%3Cspan%20style=%27color:#990044;%20tex-decoration:none;%27%3EUS%3C/span%3E%3C/a%3E&PageId=100&issue=10&search=mega-rich`

Comment: What i mean is in your jsFiddle example when you hover over the selected keywords you will see that link is broken. This script also search's for matching keywords inside HTML elements

Comment: Ah. But it's not like it was working before either so I didn't really pay attention. I'll look into it.

Comment: Appreciate your solution. This is the regex. i have been looking for the right one. Great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SInce we are using direct word matching, adding space before and after the keywords may help you,

```
var pattern = new RegExp("( "+this+" )", ["gi"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dgysc/28/

Comment: Anjith: this can be one way around.. i will keep trying as this way i will not be able to match works like `amazon,`